# Views does not show all images (as a field)

Tags: views

I use Drupal 7 and Views module.
I make Content views with several fields, one is image. I set medium image style (220x220) for it.
Views generates 12 items in one page (12 images) and not all images are visibles. Some of them are missed. If I reload the page - another become missed.
I use Chrome as a browser.

**Additional information**

The problem stil not solved. I think that reason is that Imagecash (I use drupal 7, so it is built inside) does not have enought time to resize all images which I want to show in Views page. Each originakl image is in its own size, but I ask Views to show them all like 220 by 220. 
So when I render views, some images are not shown (Chrome can not find 220 by 220 picture, because Imagecash did not do it), but then I refresh page - Imagecash do not need to convert all pictures again, it just convert some, that were not ready in previous time. So they become visible in my View.

How to fix it?

Comment: How are your results ordered ?

Comment: They are in Grid.

Comment: I mean how are they sorted ?

Comment: They are sorted by another field with numeric value.

Comment: Is the img tag missing in the source code ? Are the first 12 item always the same (not random) ?

Comment: Did you checked you File folder permission?. Style folder will be created at runtime, it might not have write permission to write images.

Comment: I did not change permissions - they are in default level.

Comment: The problem stil not solved.

Comment: Check it using firebug inspector, may be its because of css. Second you check if any template is written may be any condition preventing some images to load on page.